# How to do HTTP Requests with Android ndk

Tags: c++, http, android-ndk

I am writing a pure native application for android/ios and am having trouble with the networking code. I can't seem to get curl to compile, and either way I'd prefer to have a more object oriented library.

What is a good library to do this with or method? My current method to get json from HTTP Requests is this code using SDL2_Net

```
class HTTPRequest{
protected:
    std::map<std::string, std::string> uris;
    std::string url;

public:
    std::string host;

    HTTPRequest(std::string path) : url(path), host("182.50.154.140") {}

    void addURI(std::string parameter, std::string value){
        uris[parameter] = value;
    }

    std::string sendRequest(bool useCookie=false){
        std::string temppath = url;
        if(!uris.empty()){
            temppath += '?';
            for(auto &a : uris){
                temppath += a.first;
                temppath += '=';
                temppath += a.second;
                temppath += '&';
            }
        }
        IPaddress* addr = new IPaddress;
        SDLNet_ResolveHost(addr, host.c_str(), 8080);
        TCPsocket sock = SDLNet_TCP_Open(addr);
        std::string a = "GET ", b = " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 182.50.154.140:8080\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
        std::string c = a+temppath+b;
        SDLNet_TCP_Send(sock, c.c_str(), c.length());
        std::string d;
        char* buf = new char[1024];
        while(SDLNet_TCP_Recv(sock, buf, 1024) > 0){
            d += buf;
            delete[] buf;
            buf = new char[1024];
        }
        delete[] buf;
        SDLNet_TCP_Close(sock);
        int p = d.find("{");
        d.erase(0, p-1);
        return d;
    }
};
```

This breaks on large pages though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cURL is your best bet. here are couple of links you can try for porting cURL

http://thesoftwarerogue.blogspot.com/2010/05/porting-of-libcurl-to-android-os-using.html
https://github.com/jahrome/curl-android

If you still dont have success using cURL, try POCO

http://pocoproject.org/

Comment: I actually managed to get curl to compile using another answer on this site, though I had to modify the commands some to make them work with the latest version.

Comment: @ruler501 Would you please post your answer that you have found to this question?

Comment: @gandalf I'm sorry I can't remember. And things have changed quite a bit since then so I'm not sure it would help much anyway.